# How are some websites able to get my private IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, nat

Some websites like http://www.geoip.co.uk are able to get the private IP address of my host where as others like https://www.iplocation.net/ are unable to do so.
What is the reason behind this behaviour? I always thought that private IP is inaccessible to servers if I am using a NAT interface.
Does NAT append the public IP to the outgoing packet or it removes the private IP completely? If the latter is the case, why is the above mentioned behaviour observed?
Also, when I viewed the source code of http://www.geoip.co.uk, I observed that my IP is rendered directly as text, i.e. without any sort of call to a JavaScript function. So how does the website know my private IP *before* it even renders the web page?

[image: privateip]

The 10.9.64.58 is my private IP address (the one I get after ipconfig).

EDIT : As @simlev points out that I should add the following information: I am a university student and am connected to institute's LAN when visiting the site on my PC but I observe the same behaviour on my phone too and my phone isn't on that LAN. Imgur screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXcfN.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxoqo.png).

EDIT: Another observation which I feel is relevant : When I visit the website using https:// I get my public IP (the desired thing) but only when I visit it using http:// I get the private IP. So, is there some protocol issue we are talking about here?

Comment: What's the format of the IP being displayed? With NAT you IP doesn't leave the network.

Comment: It shouldn't be able to see your private IP, and it can't see mine.  What browser/OS are you using to access the site that is showing it to you?

Comment: @techie007 - Chrome on Windows 10. Is it okay if I add a screenshot? Is it okay if other people get to know my private IP? I mean, any security issues I could get into?

Comment: Since you are talking about web pages, your browser is about the only thing that could add this information to the packet, so it could be an  extension/plugin. You are correct, NAT replaces the source address in the IP header, but it is possible that the IP address is being placed in other areas of the data region of the Layer3 packet. As for how the server knows the IP and puts it in a page, a modern webserver is an application service that renders HTML dynamically, based on a request. An HTTP Request has a clear source IP address so the server knows it before rendering the response HTML,

Comment: @Seth - It's being shown in a xx.xx.xx.xx format. The first "xx" being 10.

Comment: @FrankThomas - Internet explorer also does the same thing. And I am sure that there isn't any extension/plugin there (I used it for the first time :p).

Comment: thats client-side script. Likely it grabs the IP, and makes an AJAX request back to the server, with your IP as argument, and then the browser rerenders the section containing the text.

Comment: @FrankThomas - Sorry for my naivety, but what does client-side mean: my side or the website's side? Because I observed the same behaviour on my phone (chrome browser, Android 6.0.1)

Comment: I don't think it's ajax: I could reproduce this even with javascript off.

Comment: Do you get the same IP when visiting the page from your phone, or a different one?

Comment: @HiredMind - Different IP's. I visited it, noted the IP, put phone on flight mode, turned to normal mode and then revisited the site. Only the last field out of the 4 fields is changed every time I repeat this cycle. Find the screenshots [here](http://i.imgur.com/58TlbNe.png) and [here](http://i.imgur.com/7Q0x6n3.png).

Comment: Sorry. I found out that the IP seen on my phone was not a private IP but rather a public IP. So, the issue wasn't exactly reproduced there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use a http proxy? In my case the web proxy forwards the internal ip, it's probably an anti-abuse feature.

A similar possibility is that your ISP only gives you a shared external ip address and then when you visit websites it also passes them your internal ip; this is in order to identify abusers: the website can provide both ips when filing an abuse report with the ISP and thanks to the internal ip the ISP is able to quickly trace the abusive user. It would be harder to do this having only the external, shared ip.

Since both the internal and external ips are passed with your request, some of the show-your-ip websites choose to show the ip the request actually comes from, while some others show the ip on whose account the request was made.

Check the headers you are sending (e.g. [here](http://www.xhaus.com/headers)). You probably have a X-Forwarded-For with your private ip added by either something on your network or one of the ISP's network devices.

For further information, see Cristopher's, Adam Katz's and Mark's answers [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94783/why-is-my-internal-ip-address-private-visible-from-the-internet). By the way, Mark provides the same suggestion as I do and links to the same website :-)

**Update:** yes, you are (very likely) using a proxy.

If you are on campus, as might be inferred from your comment, it only makes sense that your ISP (aka the university) does not connect each one of its students directly to the Internet: I'm prone to speculate that you are transparently proxied.

**Update:** As the OP noticed and correctly pointed out, the same website visited over https shows the external ip instead. This is expected, since proxies *usually* do not alter https traffic and therefore cannot add the X-Forwarded-For that gives away the internal ip address.

Comment: No, I don't use a proxy server.

Comment: Can you please share a bit more insight on your home network and ISP network? Do you get your own ip or a shared one? Static or dynamic?

Comment: Downvoters are encouraged to also comment with any constructive criticism.

Comment: I am an university student, I do not know my ISP. But I "Obtain my IP settings automatically" on Windows after connecting to Ethernet. DHCP is enabled and I guess that means that my IP is dynamically assigned. And I get my own private IP.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre This is a valuable piece of information that you should add to your question. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I am not convinced. Anyways, why then do you think the issue is being reproduced​ on my phone? My phone isn't connected to the institute LAN. I am having a hard time believing that it's something related to something on my end. I somehow am motivated to believe that the website is doing something extra than others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55518/discussion-between-simlev-and-shraddheya-shendre).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the website is taking advantage of the WebRTC security leak.

- ["Huge Security Flaw Leaks VPN Users’ Real IP-Addresses"](https://torrentfreak.com/huge-security-flaw-leaks-vpn-users-real-ip-addresses-150130/). *TorrentFreak*.  30 January 2015.

uBlock Origin ([for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) / [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm)) is capable of closing this security vulnerability. But you must go to its Settings page and check the appropriate box called "Prevent WebRTC from leaking local IP addresses".

Comment: But as I said, the issue is getting reproduced even for Internet Explorer and my phone's browser.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre I thought WebRTC was added to IE, but it seems I was wrong. Wikipedia says it hasn't.